# installing ionic to a meteor app is having an issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

When I tried

http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/meteor/bootstrapping

with the following code

```
D:\whatsapp>meteor npm install ionic-scripts --save
npm WARN angular-meteor@1.3.11 requires a peer of angular@^1.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular@^1.5.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular-animate@^1.5.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular-sanitize@^1.5.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-scripts@1.3.2 requires a peer of angular-ui-router@^0.2.13 but none was installed.
```

I had installed angular-animate, angular-sanitize and angular-ui-router packages. But I do not find any package of the name angular at atmosphere.com

What is being missed here

Comment: have you tried installing all those locally using the same --save flag?

Answer (score 0):

Could you have installed the angular things from bower, for instance by following their own tutorial? In that case, look for them in bower_components. Otherwise I would suggest keeping pure frontend dependencies, such as angular, angular-ui-router etc. in bower and use npm for backend. Perhaps write a config file for them (bower.json for bower and package.json for npm) that makes things cleaner and you can ensure installation by running npm install. Take a look at angular's tutorial for a template, it's a fairly good start.

Answer (score 0):

First you must install the package 'dab0mb:ionic-assets', with this command:

```
$ meteor add dab0mb:ionic-assets
```

..this package include the needed dependencies:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.13"
}
```

---

Another alternative could be to install all dependencies directly with this command:

```
$ meteor npm install --save angular angular-animate angular-sanitize angular-ui-router ionic-sdk ionic-scripts
```

Comment: Just finished the tutorial yesterday, but skipped the authentication section. Here is the code for reference: https://github.com/swordf1zh/test-meteor